# How to remove or hide Image Description field in TinyMCE image popup

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

First disclaimer, I am stuck in **TinyMCE v4.2** as because of some stability and business issue.

What I want to do is, hide the **Image Description** field from the Image upload popup, thats something comes with their **image** plugin.

[image]

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fn4bkug/2/) I created with my code so far I done for attaching data images in richtext.

**NB:** I know there is a option for disabling this in updated version of TinyMCE. I already read their [doc](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/) and its as simple as having just a option

```
tinymce.init({
    image_description: false
});
```

But what about the earlier version. I find no proper documentation for their older versions.

Any kind of help or idea is appreciatable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to disable the image description is a relatively new feature introducted to TinyMCE. You won't be able to find a built-in feature that is synonymous with the `image_description` property in the newer versions.

Comment: I am aware of that. And I know how to do that in newer versions. Do you have any clue about the older version like 4.2 and earlier ?

Answer (score 0):

Not great but might help you out - hide it with css

```
#mce_41-body {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: This **would not work**. As `#mce_41` is some id that is generated dynamically by **TinyMCE** itself. But let that, somehow I found the element id but still the  popover is generated dynamically. I find no hook to apply css over it.

Comment: I know i don't know your use case. The id won't change since if you run three times it's always the same and as you know unless they are using a random id generator the same code will produce the same result. However if they change version, or if you add an option which changes the dialog then that could force a new id. The only other way would be to look at the schema and see if a deep selector could hit the element div>div>div+label+input etc. But in reality that has the same loop hole.

Answer (score 0):

I know this will NOT help the OP, because as he said

> First disclaimer, I am stuck in TinyMCE v4.2 as because of some stability and business issue.

but, Stackoverflow is for everyone, and this answer can help others *(who are using newer versions than 4.2 of TinyMCE)*

here is the way to go

```
tinymce.init({
  image_description: false,
});
```

Also you can remove the dimensions of the image by the following configuration

```
tinymce.init({
  image_dimensions: false,
});
```

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/#image_description
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/#image_dimensions

Comment: I know this already. But thanks for reply, that would help others